# Failed to resolve:15.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am connecting my app to firebase for authentication "Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0" error comes if I use "implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4
" than dependencies failed if I connect again it changes dependencies in "    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
" and than error "Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this, you are indicating two versions

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

use instead one of the two and update it if necessary

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
```

the latest version was `16.0.4` at the time of this answer

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
```

Do a build - clean project if you are having any issue, just placing this implementation in your Gradle module app needs to work